# Sign of a Quadratic Form $X'AX + B'X+C$

Tags: matrices

We know that a  quadratic form: $X'AX$, in the variable $X$, the matrices having their appropriate dimensions, is negative for all $X$, iff the matrix $A$ is negative definite. Can this result be extended for the case when the quadratic expression takes the form:
$X'AX + B'X + C$?